# missing __attribute__ ((constructor)) support when building glibc for aarch64

Tags: glibc, yocto, configure, openwrt, openembedded

i am trying to build an image for ARM with OpenEmbedded/Yocto

while building glibc i get the following error message:

```
[...]
| checking whether to use .ctors/.dtors header and trailer... configure: error: missing __attribute__ ((constructor)) support??
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_configure (log file is located at /home/server/git/poky/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/glibc-initial/2.28-r0/temp/log.do_configure.21953)
ERROR: Task (/home/server/git/poky/meta/recipes-core/glibc/glibc-initial_2.28.bb:do_configure) failed with exit code '1'
```

the layer i am trying to build the layer [meta-openwrt](https://github.com/kraj/meta-openwrt)

my local.conf looks like this:

```
MACHINE ?= "jetson-tx1"
DISTRO ?= "poky"
PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= "package_rpm"
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES ?= "debug-tweaks"
USER_CLASSES ?= "buildstats image-mklibs image-prelink"
PATCHRESOLVE = "noop"
BB_DISKMON_DIRS ??= "\
    STOPTASKS,${TMPDIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,${DL_DIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,${SSTATE_DIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,/tmp,100M,100K \
    ABORT,${TMPDIR},100M,1K \
    ABORT,${DL_DIR},100M,1K \
    ABORT,${SSTATE_DIR},100M,1K \
    ABORT,/tmp,10M,1K"
PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-qemu-native = " sdl"
PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-nativesdk-qemu = " sdl"
CONF_VERSION = "1"
SSTATE_MIRRORS = "\
     file://.* http://sstate.yoctoproject.org/dev/PATH;downloadfilename=PATH \n \
     file://.* http://sstate.yoctoproject.org/2.5/PATH;downloadfilename=PATH \n \
     file://.* http://sstate.yoctoproject.org/2.6/PATH;downloadfilename=PATH \n \
     "
IMAGE_CLASSES += "image_types_tegra"
IMAGE_FSTYPES = "tegraflash"
TARGET_CFLAGS += " -lcrypt"
```

With the help of google i found some [mailinglists](https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=lfs-dev@linuxfromscratch.org&q=subject:%22Re%3A%20missing%20__attribute__%20((constructor))%20support%3F%22&o=newest&f=1) where someone says that i need to add "'libc_cv_ctors_header=yes' to the end of the configure invocation".
But i do not know how to do that.
`core-image-sato` works.

Comment: What's the target triplet of your compiler and linker? It should be something like `aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu`. I assume you are using a bare-metal ELF target instead.

Comment: Oh, i thought using the bitbake would assure only one target compiler would be used (in my case aarch64-poky-linux...) how can i determine which is used?

Answer (score 1):

I've just met this problem, you saw the answer here:

http://lists.linuxfromscratch.org/pipermail/lfs-dev/2011-August/064955.html
https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-from-scratch-13/error-compiling-glibc-2-28-in-lfs-8-3-a-4175644816/

adding 'libc_cv_ctors_header=yes' to the end of the configure invocation

means to add libc_cv_ctors_header=yes to the end of the ./configure args, as the guy on linuxquestions.org did in his answer

Comment: i.e.:  ```../configure --prefix=/opt/glibc${libc_version} --disable-werror libc_cv_ctors_header=yes``` -- this helped with compiling older glibc on AWS EC2 x86